# joomla contact form module

Tags: joomla

Is there a good free joomla contact us extension that can be used without  much configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several form components that are very good. If the person using the component is pretty technically savvy, then Chronoforms is the way to go. It allows a lot of options including executing code, emailing form contents, saving forms contents to the DB, curl operations, all kinds of stuff.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508

If the user is a little less technical and just needs forms that email results, you should look at BreezingForms or RSForm, both are easier to use, but do not offer as much latitude.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4709

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/2265

Answer (score 1):

FoxContact is probably the simplest and most elegant way to add a contact form to a Joomla website. It offers template changes, multiple contact e-mails, and the form possibilities are endless. Only downfall is the small Branding links on the bottom of the forms which can be removed at a nominal fee.

http://www.fox.ra.it/

or to see in action on my sit
http://cnclinks.com/gcnav/book-a-tee-time

Answer (score 1):

ChronoForms (http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/9-chronoforms.html) is a GREAT 'free' form component that works in ALL JOOMLA versions.

It includes a 'easy form wizard' for "drag and drop" form creation. In addition, it easily allows the form data to be passed to pages, sent via email and stored in a database table.

VERY EASY to you and very flexible.

Todd